# Using XML attribute value as XSL variable

Tags: xml, variables, xslt

So I am trying to generate xml based on an xml boolean radio option. But as I am new to xsl in general, the variable concept at this depth is a bit out of my reach.

My XML:

```
<item name="commentOutNode" pathid="commentOutNode">
  <radio>
    <option label="Yes" value="true"/>
    <option label="No" value="false" selected="t"/>
  </radio>
</item>
```

My Current XSL:

```
<xsl:variable name="commentOutNode" select="commentOutNode/@value[.]"/>
***
(a ways down)
***
<xsl:when test="$commentOutNode = true">
    # do this stuff
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
    # do this other stuff
</xsl:otherwise>
```

How can I leverage the selected radio option's value for the xsl variable and then test what it is?

Comment: Fixed it.. sorry I have another section with commentOutFarm as well. This code section will be duplicated for farms just as it would be created for nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `value` attribute of the selected option of the item with name `commentOutNode` use the XPath:

```
//item[@name='commentOutNode']/radio/option[@selected='t']/@value
```

To set a variable with such value:

```
<xsl:variable name="selectedValue" select="//item[@name='commentOutNode']/radio/option[@selected='t']/@value"/>
```

To test the variable:

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="$selectedValue='true'">
      . . . 
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
       . . . 
   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: wouldn't you use //item[@name='commentOutNode']/radio/option[@value='true'] to leverage the true/false value?

Comment: Or wouldn't this be correct //item[@name='commentOutNode']/radio/option/@value and then <xsl:when test="$selectedValue='true'">

Comment: I am not sure what are you after. `//item[@name='commentOutNode']/radio/option[@value='true']` returns the `option` element with attribute `value` equal `true` - that is not the selected one though, isn't it?  `//item[@name='commentOutNode']/radio/option/@value` return a node-set with all the values - comparing it with a string just compares the first one...